# Youtube Content ID API has not been used - error 403

Tags: youtube-api, google-api-php-client

I'm trying to get my `content-owner-id` for upload videos to other channels that I have, as described [here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/partner/code_samples/php#upload_and_monetize_a_video__service_account_authorization_).

I'm using the code below to get `content-owner-id`: (PHP)

```
$youtubePartner = new Google_Service_YouTubePartner($this->client);
$contentOwnersListResponse = $youtubePartner->contentOwners->listContentOwners(
                array('fetchMine' => true));
$contentOwnerId = $contentOwnersListResponse['items'][0]['id'];
```

And this is the error I got:

> A service error occurred: Error calling GET
>   googleapis.com/youtube/partner/v1/contentOwners?fetchMine=true:
>   (403) Access Not Configured. Youtube Content ID API has not been used
>   in project XXXXXXXXXXXXX before or it is disabled. Enable it by
>   visiting
>   console.developers.google.com/apis/api/youtubePartner/overview?project=XXXXXXXXXX
>   then retry. If you enabled this API recently, wait a few minutes for
>   the action to propagate to our systems and retry.

I tried to go the the link https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/youtubePartner/overview?project=XXXXXXXXXX but I get "The API doesn't exist or you don't have permission to access it".

Then I searched on google and find out that I need to become a CMS youtube account (I'm also a youtube partner). I also tried to go to cms.youtube.com and log in with my youtube account but I got:

> Your Google Account is not linked with YouTube Content Manager. Please
>   try a different account or contact your Technical Account Manager for
>   assistance.

Can anyone explain me how to connect to CMS account?

Answer (score 0):

Based from this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28111212/how-do-i-get-revenue-reports-from-a-youtube-cms-account-using-an-api-for-an-mcn/28148304#28148304):

> You don't see it in the list auf available APIs, unless your account is connected to a CMS and some time has past... It takes 7-14 days unless the Content ID API is available for your account. This is a information i got from the support, but they told me, that it is an automated step.

Your account needs to be connected with a content owner. Be noted that a content owner and a partnered channel are not the same thing.

From this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/analytics/v1/#Parameters), to request data from a YouTube Content Owner, you need to set the `ids` parameter value to `contentOwner==OWNER_NAME`, where `OWNER_NAME` is the content owner ID.

Check these related SO questions:

- [How do I get revenue reports from a YouTube CMS account using an API (for an MCN)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28111212/how-do-i-get-revenue-reports-from-a-youtube-cms-account-using-an-api-for-an-mcn)
- [Using the YouTube Analytics API with a CMS account](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15554106/using-the-youtube-analytics-api-with-a-cms-account)